# Caddyfile set password securely

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

i have only started to use caddy and i am trying to figure out how to create an endpoint with a secure `basicauth` configured.

given a configuration like this:

```
test.my-domain.com {
    basicauth / testuser testpassword
    proxy / http://192.168.1.1:5000
}
```

i want to know how i can make it so that the password is secured and not in plain text.

i have created a docker secret called `TEST_PASSWORD` which is imported to a file at the location `/run/secrets/TEST_PASSWORD`. the content of this file is the password.

according to the documentation, the `import` directive will read content of the file and replace the line. https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile#import

```
test.my-domain.com {
    basicauth / testuser import /run/secrets/TEST_PASSWORD
    proxy / http://192.168.1.1:5000
}
```

but this does not work. i have also tried with the line:

- `basicauth / testuser {import /run/secrets/TEST_PASSWORD}`
- `basicauth / testuser {%import /run/secrets/TEST_PASSWORD%}`

does anyone know what i am doing wrong here.